# Electron can't write files on windows 10

Tags: node.js, filesystems, windows-10, electron

Using fs-extra to write files is failing on windows 10. The [outputFile method](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/outputFile.md) is supposed to create any missing directory before writing, but it's throwing an error. I know the Downloads directory already exists, though.

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\josh\Downloads\2018-01-13_15:14:11.png'

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const app = require('electron').remote.app
const moment = require('moment')

let dataURL = this.$.canvas.toDataURL()
let filename = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD_HH:mm:ss') + '.png'
let buffer = new Buffer(dataURL.replace('data:image/png;base64', ''), 'base64')
let filepath = path.resolve(app.getPath('downloads'), filename)
fs.outputFile(filepath, buffer, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use colon ':' in the filename on Windows.

From [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:
>
> - The following reserved characters:
>
>   - < (less than)
>   - > (greater than)
>   - : (colon)
>   - " (double quote)
>   - / (forward slash)
>   - \ (backslash)
>   - | (vertical bar or pipe)
>   - ? (question mark)
>   - * (asterisk)
> - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
> - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File Streams.
> - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.